# How to do proper Column Filtering with React-Virtualized - Advice needed?

Tags: react-virtualized

I have a react-virtualized table where column sorting is enabled. My plan is to add a `filter icon` next to column headers and do a [Material-UI popover](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/popover) when someone clicks on it.

So here is what I did:
I enabled headerRenderer

`headerRenderer= {this.renderHeader}`

My headerRenderer returns a component

```
  renderHeader = (value) => {
    // console.log(value)
    return <ColumnFilterContainer label= {value.label} />
  }
```

ColumnFilterContainer is as follows.

```
import React from 'react'
import ContentClear from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/clear'
import FilterList from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/filter-list'

const ColumnFilterContainer = (props) => {
  const {label} = props
  return <span>{label} <a onClick={console.log('TEST')} ><FilterList /></a></span>
}

export default ColumnFilterContainer
```

But when I click on the svg-icon it consoles out the 'TEST' but also resorts the table. How can I achieve what I would like to do. Is it doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Table` listens for clicks on sortable headers. (That is, columns that aren't tagged as `disableSort` that belong to a `Table` with a `sort` callback.)

In your case, if you have something within your sortable header that shouldn't trigger sorting- just prevent the event from bubbling and you should be fine. :)

Alternately you could also just ignore the next call to your `sort` function but I think that would be a hackish solution.